# cannot deploy application in Glassfish 3.1.2, Icefaces 1.8.1 with jsf 1.2

Tags: glassfish-3, jsf-1.2, icefaces-1.8

I write a application use bundled IceFaces 1.8.1 and jsf 1.2. but it cannot deploy in Glassfish 3.1.2.

The error message is

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:  org.icefaces.x.context.BridgeFacesContext2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the answer to this question:
[JSF 1.2 app not working with GlassFish v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333330/jsf-1-2-app-not-working-with-glassfish-v3)
Also check: 
https://wikis.oracle.com/display/GlassFish/JavaServerFacesRI#JavaServerFacesRI-IwanttouseMojarra1.2inGlassfishv3

Also: 
http://www.icesoft.org/JForum/posts/list/17044.page#sthash.4uwE5n1N.F9JR7G2x.dpbs

However, I have the same problem on Glassfish 4 and did not succeed yet (deployment ok, but I cannot view my pages due to: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.icefaces.x.context.BridgeFacesContext2

UPDATE:

Checkout http://anonsvn.icesoft.org/repo/icefaces/tags/icefaces-1.8.2a/icefaces/
Call ant build.all inside icefaces folder.
Copy the icefaces jars from lib folder inside your .war WEB-INF/lib (that means remove icefaces1.8.2.jar, icefaces-comps-1.8.2.jar, icefaces-facelets-1.8.2.jar and replace them with the same new jars - 1.8.2a version from lib folder).

The explanation is here: http://www.icesoft.org/JForum/posts/list/16568.page#sthash.3XjXYufx.dpbs :

NOTE: The ICEfaces 1.8.2a release consists of official ICEfaces 1.8.2 release plus a patch to resolve issues when deploying a JSF 1.1 or JSF 1.2 ICEfaces project to Glassfish 3. It is necessary to use the ICEfaces 1.8.2a release libraries on Glassfish 3, as the original ICEfaces 1.8.2 runtime libraries will fail with a "JSF 2 not supported" error when used in a JEE5/JSF 1.2 project.  - See more at: http://www.icesoft.org/JForum/posts/list/16568.page#sthash.3XjXYufx.dpuf

Followed steps from here: http://www.icesoft.org/JForum/posts/list/17044.page#sthash.4uwE5n1N.F9JR7G2x.dpbs see deryk.sinotte's post starting with: "I did the following"

After deploying the .war with 1.8.2a icefaces jars the error went away